# How do I extract the SMTP envelope and header with Perl?

Tags: perl, smtp

What is  SMTP Envelope and SMTP header and what is the relationship between those? How do I extract them with Perl?

Comment: In order to describe best how you find them you would need to describe the platform and languages you are using

Comment: want to find in linux and perl

Comment: Well, SMTP is described in its RFC. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2812 As I've said before, there is a lot that you can do to help yourself before you come here.

Comment: The correct link to the RFC about SMTP: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2821

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An SMTP message contains a set of headers such as From, To, CC, Subject and a whole range of other stuff.

An SMTP Envelope is simply the name given to a small set of header prefixed to the standard SMTP message when the message is moved about by the Message Transport Agent (ie. the SMTP server).  The most common envelope headers are X-Sender, X-Receiver and Received.

For example Microsofts SMTP Server will add the X-Sender and a series of X-Receiver headers to the top of a message when it drops the message into its Drop folder.  There will be one X-Receiver for each post box that matches the domain the Drop folder is for.

Another example is SMTP servers add a Receive: header when it receives a message from another SMTP server.  This header gives various details of the exchange.  Hence most emails on the tinternet once arrived at the final destination will have a series of Receive headers indicating the SMTP server hops the message took to arrive.  Usually servers remove the X-Sender, X-Receiver headers when the message is finally moved to a POP3 mailbox.

**Accessing Headers**

On the windows platform the only way I've found to access the envelope headers is to simply open and parse the eml file.  Its a pretty simple format (`name`: `value` CR LF).

Again on the windows platform the main set of message headers and body parts can be accessed using the CDOSYS.dll COM based set of objects.  How you would do this on other platforms I don't know.  However the header format is quite straight forward as per the envelope headers, its accessing the body parts that would require more creative coding.

Comment: Other MTAs will add the headers as X-Envelope-From: and X-Envelope-To:

Answer (score 4):

The envelope is the addressing information sent to the server during the initial conversation via the "MAIL FROM:" and "RCPT TO:" commands.

The SMTP header is the collection of header lines which are sent after the DATA command is issued.

How you find them is dependant on how/where you're getting the message from, and we'd need a lot more clues to attempt to answer that.

Answer (score 1):

For Perl email related stuff have a look at the [Perl Email Project](http://emailproject.perl.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can actually think of three different things here.  There are the directives that were exchanged between the SMTP MTAs (during each hop the message took) ... the headers that were generated by the MUA and headers that were added (or modified) by MTAs along the route that a given message traversed.

The "envelope" refers to the information provided to the MTA (normally the most recent or final destination MTA).  The sender includes a set of headers after the DATA directive in the SMTP connection (separated from the body of the message by a blank line ... but double check the RFC if that's specifically supposed to be a CR/LF pair).  Note that the local MTA may add additonal headers and might even modify some headers before storing or forwarding the message.

(Normally it should only add Received-by: headers).

Some MTAs are configured to add X-Envelope-To: and/or X-Envelope-From: headers.  Some of them will still filter the contents of these headers (for example to prevent leakage of blind copies).  (Senario: the original MUA had a BCC: line directory that a number of people be copied on the message with their names all appearing to one another in the CC: headers; for each recipient domain (MX result) the MTA will only issue RCPT TO: for only the subset of addresses for which the host if the appropriate result (its own hub, smarthost, or any valid MX for the target) --- thus any subsets of recipients who share an MX  with each other would see leakage in the X-Envelope-To: headers generated by MTAs that were sloppy about the handling of this detail).

Also not that an Envelope-From line would only contain a host/domain name as supplied by the HELO FROM: or EHLO FROM: directives in the SMTP exchange.  It cannot be used as a return address, for replies for example.